# Text Manipulation in SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a column named `body`(`ntext`,`null`).  Basically anything in the body of the message will come out as one string of text.  See example:

```
Report Count SITE Type ACCOUNT NUMBER STMT CD COLL SCHEME Previously Touched   Resi Aging 98 Cleveland - 609 Former 22449903 1 RQ-1 1160201
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
Report Count   SITE              Type   ACCOUNT NUMBER  STMT  CD            
98            Cleveland - 609    Former  22449903        1     RQ-1 1160201
```

How can I get this output?   Would it be easier to do in EXCEL using VBA verses SQL?

I am not an expert in SQL.  I am still learning.

Comment: If at all possible you should change the table. The (n)text datatype has been deprecated in favor of (n)varchar(max) since sql2005. You will have to convert/cast this datatype to a (var)char datatype before you do anything with it anyway. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You COULD try to get this out of Sql but I think most would agree that Sql is not designed for extensively formatting text.

As a DBA, I would steer you towards making those fields discrete if possible using normalization or at the very least having a key/value pair table rather than a blob of text that represents both fields and data.

You could also consider a datatype of XML if you find that you need to store different fields and different responses for each row.